# Connecting Database in codeigniter 2.02

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do i connect database in codeigniter because there is not any core array in autoload.php i am trying to search it there not any core array as like pervious version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In application/config/database.php you place the settings to connect to your DB, for ex:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
//and so on...
```

Then, you might want to autoload it to have always at hand and avoid calling the library often. You put it in the

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

which is on line 55 of application/config/autoload.php

Then you can just call it in any controller or method (or custom libraries) with

```
//$this->db->...  // method may vary
```

look in [User Guide on database driver](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) for all details and methods and the useful Active Record (sortof), and if you've problem just ask.